# Device Orientation upside down not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios9, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a single view application coded in swift.

I have set Device orientation Portrait and Upside down. Neither landscape orientation is supported.

When running in both the sim and on a 5s turning the device upside down has no effect and  `UI` remains in the stock `portrait` position.

I've checked the storyboard `orientation` and this is set to inferred.

I've clearly missed something so any help will be appreciated.

I am targeting `IOS 9.0, building using XCode 7.3` (7D175).

Comment: try adding `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow` in you appdelegate and return needed orientation

Answer (score 0):

Try tu put this on your plist file

```plist
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
</array>
```

And also verify on your target on *general tab* on *Deployment info* to have this:

[image]